# Django Model designing in OneToOneField and ManyToManyField

Tags: django, django-models

I am writing a Django app movie Seat Booking, I am going through trouble designing a simple model.

at first here you go for my current models:

```
from django.db import models
from django.contrib.auth import get_user_model

class Seats(models.Model):
    seat_choice = (
        ('AA', 'AA'),
        ('AB', 'AB'),
        ('BA', 'BA'),
        ('BB', 'BB'),
        ('CA', 'CA'),
        ('CB', 'CB')
    )
    name = models.CharField(choices=seat_choice, max_length=2)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name


class Booking(models.Model):
    hall = models.OneToOneField(Seats)
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**I want a user can buy/book one or more than one seats but the same user or other user cant buy a seat that already booked by someone or himself**

But the problem is, my current models, not working like what I want...
Currently, it is working like if a user buys any ticket, the same user cant buys the ticket that bought by himself already! **but the problem is, now another user can buy the ticket that already booked by someone** and I don't want this at all.

I want if a seat booked already by anyone, no one can book it again later but it can be unbooked by the user who booked!

Can anyone please help me to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make the field `unique` to solve your current state, but I think one seat should be available for the other days. So, it'll better if you use the `unique_for_date` attribute. [Source](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/fields/#unique-for-date)

The Booking Model will be like the following:

```py
class Booking(models.Model):

    hall = models.OneToOneField(Seats, unique_for_date='created')
    user = models.ForeignKey(get_user_model(), on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created = models.DateField(auto_now_add=True)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it helps me a lot, one more question... I want to replace created field into show, then how  can i unique together? I mean, i will use a named show that is foreignkey of Show model and remove the created field, then how can i uniqe them?

Comment: If you think, it helps you then plz accept the answer.

Comment: To make a field unique you have to use `unique=True`. For example: `show = models.ForeignKey('Show', unique=True)`

Comment: It throws me following error: WARNINGS:
booking.Booking.show: (fields.W342) Setting unique=True on a ForeignKey has the same effect as using a OneToOneField.
 HINT: ForeignKey(unique=True) is usually better served by a OneToOneField.

Comment: created_by was worked nice but if i try with show, it is not working

Comment: Would you please describe your query including the code snippets? I find difficult to understand from your lines.